# Flutter - Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve user data using a DocumentSnapshot. However I am getting a casterror because the instance that I created is pointing to null. So I tried calling the method getUserProfileData in the initState method to see if it could assign a value to my DocumentSnapshot instance but I still get that error. Please may anyone kindly help.

```
//DocumentSnapshot instance that is null
DocumentSnapshot? userDocument;

  getUserProfileData() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      userDocument = event;
    });
  }

 @override
  void initState() {
    getUserProfileData();
//This is where the castError occurs because userDocument is null
    nameController.text = userDocument!.get('name');
    userNameController.text = userDocument!.get('username');

    try {
      descriptionController.text = userDocument!.get('description');
    } catch (e) {
      descriptionController.text = '';
    }

    try {
      followers = userDocument!.get('followers').length;
    } catch (e) {
      followers = 0;
    }

    try {
      following = userDocument!.get('following').length;
    } catch (e) {
      following = 0;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use StreamBuilder for firstore-snapshot.

```dart
  late final stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {....},
    );
  }
```

Also error can be bypass like

```dart
  getUserProfileData() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      userDocument = event;
      /// all those stuff here
        nameController.text = userDocument!.get('name');
        userNameController.text = userDocument!.get('username');
               ..........
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution but I ended up invoking the method using GetXController.

Comment: `GetXController` :(. try riverpod/bloc

Answer (score 0):

Try use async/await for `getUserProfileData()` function

```
getUserProfileData() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      userDocument = event;
    });
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    getUserProfileData();

// Replace with default value case userDocument is null
    nameController.text = userDocument!.get('name') ?? "";
    userNameController.text = userDocument!.get('username') ?? "";

    try {
      descriptionController.text = userDocument!.get('description') ?? "";
    } catch (e) {
      descriptionController.text = '';
    }

    try {
      followers = userDocument!.get('followers').length ?? 0;
    } catch (e) {
      followers = 0;
    }

    try {
      following = userDocument!.get('following').length ?? 0;
    } catch (e) {
      following = 0;
    }
  }
```

**Async** determines that a method will be asynchronous, that is, it will not return something immediately, so the application can continue executing other tasks while processing is not finished.

**await** serves to determine that the application must wait for a response from a function before continuing execution. This is very important because there are cases where a function depends on the return of another.

**a ?? b** means that if the value of a is null, the value b will be assigned